# Error by parsing selected Panel index in JQuery UI Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the index of the selected panel from my Jquery UI Tab.
I got following JS - Snippet:

```
function getSelectedPanel(){
     var values = new Object();
     values.activepanel =  $("#tabs").tabs( "option", "active" );
     var json = JSON.stringify(values);
     return json;
}
```

After that, I'm using this value in my Java - Code like this:

```
public String checkselectedPanel(json) {

    JSONObject values = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(json);
    String activepanel = (String)values.get("activepanel");

     // ...
}
```

Everythime I get an exception despite the variable "**activepanel**" is filled with values, I could see it by debugging. I also tried to parse the value into an Integer, with the same result.

Comment: Can you please add a fiddle with the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getSelectedPanel(){
 var values = new Object();
 values.activepanel =  String($("#tabs").tabs( "option", "active" ));
 var json = JSON.stringify(values);
 return json;
```

}

Your code in Java:

```
public String checkselectedPanel(json) {

JSONObject values = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(json);
String activepanel = (String)values.get("activepanel");

 // do stuff
```

}

Tried it myself, seems to work, please post your exception next time as well.